# Elasticsearch geo query intersects percentage

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch in order to search by geo query. I'm looking into geo shape queries and what I want to achieve is the `INTERSECTS` functionality but with a percentage. For example I want to be able to say, rectangle A intersects rectangle B by 70%. Elasticsearch doesn't provide this (as far as I know). How can I shape my data (4 geopoints for every location) in order to achieve something like this?

Comment: Hi, Did you figure it out?.. i need the same thing.  Thanks

Comment: Hi @אVי unfortunately no. I don't believe this possible without some custom plugin

Comment: Thanks
eventually i did it with turf js.

Comment: So you processed and obtained the intersection percentages only on the client side? How was the performance? Thanks!

Comment: @FlorinVîrdol Hi, in the end we decided that it's not worth the effort and the potential performance degradation. I don't really remember the details.